# files not loading correctly while testing angular 2 with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to run Jasmine test on my angular app and get the following message while debugging using Developer Tools

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:45870/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js/testing

I think what is trying to load is incorrect because I can see this node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js and core.umd.js is a file and not folder. However there is a foldler node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/testing.

Please see my Systemjs.config.js file below

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      '@progress/kendo-angular-grid': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
        '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl',
        '@telerik/kendo-intl': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
       'primeng': 'node_modules/primeng',
       'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-grid': {
          main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl': {
          main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl': {
          main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'primeng': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have all the Angular files required for running the application, set up in your `systemjs.config.js` file. But in your tests, you are trying to import things that are in the Angular *testing* modules. These are in different bundles, which are not (rightly) configured in the application `systemjs.config.js`.

What you need to do also map those testing modules. But you should do this in a separate file that you only load for tests. If you look at the [Angular quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) project, there is a [karma-test-shim.js](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/karma-test-shim.js) SystemJS config mapping for the testing modules.

Even after fixing that, you may still run into other errors (can't tell without seeing the jasmine set up. There is a lot more involved with setting this up. You see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V8PxsHD79wGTWyaA2ctr?p=preview) for a complete set up.

Personally though, I would recommend setting up Karma. You can check out [this article](https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html), where I do a pretty thorough walk-through of making the conversion from Browser/Jasmine to Karma/Jasmine.